# powerbi.embed() not returning Report type

Tags: javascript, typescript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have succesfully embedded a report using a `powerbi` service:

```
const report = powerbi.embed(...)
```

Now `report` is of type `Embed` and not `Report` as expected. Thus, no Report-specific functions are available (at least typescript-wise). What am i missing?

EDIT: The `report` object is indeed an instance of the `Report` class, but the type is still `Embed`. Do i need to install additional typings for `powerbi-client`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to install any additional typings. Just return the powerbi.embed as Report and it will works.

```
const report = powerbi.embed(.....) as Report
```